# Google Chrome font won't change after changing font settings

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

I'm trying to change my font for google chrome, so I go onto font settings and change my fonts to what I want, but then when I restart my browser, the font hasn't changed at all, so I check the font settings and they're still put to what I had changed them to, but chrome hasn't changed at all. I'm on windows 11 if that changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I was able to get my font restored after using *Reset Settings* in Chrome's settings page. Maybe there is an easier way.